# is the code given in description is executable in Windows system?

Tags: php, mysql, command-line, shellexecute, windows-shell

is the code given is executable in Windows system? as it seems to be Linux commands

```
   echo 'create database foo2' | mysql -uroot
    mysqldump --skip-triggers -uroot foo | mysql -uroot foo2
```

> **EDITED**
>   I am executing the following code but I am not getting what I expect..

```
<?php 
mysql_connect('localhost','root','********');
echo 'create database pranav_chk'. | mysql -u root
    mysqldump --skip-triggers -u root pranav_test | mysql -u root pranav_chk;
 ?>
```

Comment: You can't simply stuff the contents of a unix shell script into a php script.

Comment: @Volkerk, thats what I want to know, how to do it, I am not aware of it, please guide me, I hope u have understood what I am trying to do here....

Comment: Just put the two lines of code in a file called xyz.cmd or xyz.bat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code uses three command-line features:

- An `echo` command
- Connecting commands via pipes (the `|` symbol)
- The `mysql` command line client

All three are available and work identically (to the degree they're used here) on Windows and on Linux, so the code is in fact portable.

**Edit:** The code needs to be run in the shell, you can't just put it into a PHP script. You have to use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), something like this:

```
<?php
  exec("echo 'create database foo2' | mysql -uroot");
  exec("mysqldump --skip-triggers -uroot foo | mysql -uroot foo2");
?>
```

However, the `mysql_connect()` call before won't do you any good, because it's only valid for the PHP script. You'll have to do authentication via the command line directly. Alternatively, you could use it and [`mysql_create_db()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-create-db.php) to replace the first `exec()` line.

Answer (score 1):

It should work yes, assuming mysql and mysqldump are in the windows PATH variable. Although you should add a space between the -u and the root.

Answer (score 1):

3 notes.

First, the database connection in the PHP script is not shared with the outside system command.

Second, you need to supply password to the command line.

Three, use the exec function to run your command.

For example:

```
<?php
$PASSWORD="YOURPASSWORD";
exec("echo 'create database foo2' | mysql -u root -p $PASSWORD");
?>
```

Not tested but thats the general idea.

Comment: Pls correct the answer by NOT seperating "-uroot" and "-p$password"

Comment: That is the correct way. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html